# magento category urls

Tags: url, magento

I'm getting "-1" appended to some of my category urls. e.g. bedroom.html becomes bedroom-1.html. How do I stop this happening and correct the current ones.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens if you have duplicate identifiers ('URL key'). If you've removed/renamed the duplicates, you might need to run the Rewrite refresh/re-index from the Cache Management page under "System".